# Swiftui Navigation Question Using NavigationLink to specific Tab

Tags: swiftui, tabs, swiftui-navigationlink

Basically I have the below listed code working with the exception of getting to view 4. I'm guessing I've messed up the binding in some way, I just can't figure out what. Can anyone help make this happen? Here's where I am with code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var activeView: Int = 0
    @State var activeNavigationLink: Int = 0
    
    let items = ["View1", "View2", "View3", "View4"]
    
    func navigationLinkBinding(id: Int) -> Binding<Bool> {
        .init { () -> Bool in
            activeNavigationLink == id
        } set: { (newValue) in
            if newValue {
                activeNavigationLink = id
            } else {
                activeNavigationLink = 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: Binding<Int> (
                    get: {
                        activeView
                    }, set: {
                        activeView = $0
                        activeNavigationLink = 0
                    }))
        {
            NavigationView {
                HStack(spacing: 40) {
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 2), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        
                        Text("To View 3")
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 3), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        
                        Text("To View 4")

                    }
                    
                    
                }.navigationTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "a.circle")
                Text("Main")
            }
            .tag(0)
            
            Text("View 5")
                .padding()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "b.circle")
                    Text("View 3")
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
        
    }
}
```

The below is in the same file as the above. It is where view 4 resides:

```
struct NewView: View {
    
    let items = ["View1", "View2", "View3", "View4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TabView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    Text(items[2])
                }
                .tabItem {Image(systemName: "a.circle"); Text("GREEN")}
                .id(2)
                
                
                
                
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    Text(items[3])
                }
                .tabItem {Image(systemName: "b.circle"); Text("BLUE")}
                .id(3)

                
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what happened to the other comments, but if anyone needs the answer, I came up with it on my own. Thanks to the user who had replied prior... not sure what happened to your answer.

Comment: Feel free to add your own solution as an answer to your question to help others. :)

Comment: Sure thing. Adding now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
//  ContentView.swift
//  navtest
//
//  Created by MRBarclay on 4/9/22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var activeView: Int = 0
    @State var activeNavigationLink: Int = 0
    
    func navigationLinkBinding(id: Int) -> Binding<Bool> {
        .init { () -> Bool in
            activeNavigationLink == id
        } set: { (newValue) in
            if newValue {
                activeNavigationLink = id
            } else {
                activeNavigationLink = 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: Binding<Int> (
            get: {
                activeView
            }, set: {
                activeView = $0
                activeNavigationLink = 0
            }))
        {
            VStack {
                Text("Main 1")
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "1.circle"); Text("Main 1")}
            .tag(1)
            
            NavigationView {
                HStack(spacing: 40) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Main 2")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 1), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 1), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 1")
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("Main 2")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 2), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 2), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 2")
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("Main 2")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 3), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 3), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 3")
                        
                    }
                    
                }.navigationTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "2.circle"); Text("Main 2")}
            .tag(2)
            
            NavigationView {
                HStack(spacing: 40) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Main 3")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 1), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 1), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 1")
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("Main 3")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 2), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 2), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 2")
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("Main 3")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 3), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 3), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 3")
                        
                    }
                    
                }.navigationTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "3.circle"); Text("Main 3")}
            .tag(3)
            
            NavigationView {
                HStack(spacing: 40) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Main 4")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 1), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 1), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 1")
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("Main 4")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 2), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 2), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 2")
                        
                    }
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("Main 4")
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: NewView(selectedItem: 3), isActive: navigationLinkBinding(id: 3), label: {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.green)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            }).isDetailLink(false)
                        Text("To Sub 3")
                        
                    }
                    
                }.navigationTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "4.circle"); Text("Main 4")}
            .tag(4)
        }
    }
}

struct NewView: View {
    
    @State var selectedItem: Int
    @State var activeNavigationLink: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem) {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                Text("One")
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "a.circle"); Text("BLUE")}
            .tag(1)
            
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                Text("Two")
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "b.circle"); Text("GREEN")}
            .tag(2)
            
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.orange)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                Text("Three")
            }
            .tabItem {Image(systemName: "b.circle"); Text("ORANGE")}
            .tag(3)
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add there is probably some unnecessary code in there. It's a test file... but hey, it works... Xcode 13.

Comment: I should also add, the innermost views are set to swipe.